# How to store cookies received from Sakai login and pass it to other rest calls to Sakai

Tags: javascript, java, cookies, http-headers, sakai

I am trying to play Scorm contents via Sakai LMS from my application. For doing that, I want to get the user session after logging in to Sakai and pass it for any other calls. I am able to get the user session cookie after login from Sakai via a rest call, but I am not able to pass the "Set-cookie" in the header or Store the cookie manually so that I will be able to use them to call other URL's that plays the Scorm or invokes other functionalities for the current user.
How can I use the cookie returned by the getSession API to do other functionalities for the logged in user?

I have tried passing the response header from the login to make the next API call.

I have tried forming the Session and adding it to the header after removing the 'HTML only' like "SAKAI2SESSIONID="+session+".domain; Path=/;"

I have tried passing the session id and cookie in the response and manually storing it in the local storage

-----1------

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpPost);
            Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
            String session=EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
response.setHeader("Set-Cookie","SAKAI2SESSIONID="+session);
```

----3----

```
function getSessionId() {
                let data = {
                    password: "pass",
                    userId: "user"
                }
                fetch('http:ldomain/sakai/getSession', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    body: JSON.stringify(data), 
                    headers:{
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
                    },

                })
                .then(response => response.json())
                .then(response => {
                    localStorage.setItem('SAKAI2SESSIONID', response.entity.cookie[0])
                    document.cookie= response.entity.cookie[0];
                })
                .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))
            }
```

even though I tried all these when I try to hit Scorm URL after doing this, it redirects me to the login page again.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to make your application an [LTI provider?](https://longsight.screenstepslive.com/s/sakai_help/m/30369/l/295775-what-is-lti) That is the supported way of using Sakai credentials with it.